# Could not load file or assembly error while using the application Users Program Menu

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

I have a winform application which i have build as Setup by using windows Setup project.Now with the help of setup i have successfully installed the application into my system.On checking the installation folder i can notice all the external .dlls are present there along with the application .exe.Now i started the application from the Users program Menu and on button click from the application screen i am getting error as ..

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EPPlus, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

While the file is present in the folder .Also when i am trying to use the application from the installation folder i am able to access all the features with out any error.

Why is this happening.Please help me to resolve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this issue, open the project `Properties`->open `Debug`->set `Working Directory` as "Start Menu" folder (which is `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\YourPragram`). And then start debugging to recreate the binding error.

It is likely your application expects `CurrentDirectory` set as the app folder. If it is, you should set it explicitly in code. In the `Main` method, add this

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
```

With this line, even if application is started from `Start Menu`, the `CurrentDirectory` is the app folder, not Start Menu.

You can also use Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer) to diagnose binding error.

1. start Visual Studio Command prompt (as Administrator).
2. run command "Fuslogvw.exe"
3. click "Settings", and in Log Settings dialog, select "log bind error to disk", and check "Enable custom log path", set a path like "C:\"
4. run your program from start menu, and after the exception occur, go to C:\Default to get a binding log for EPPlus.dll.

The diagnostic result looks like this, you can see the attempted path.

> LOG: 
>   Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/kennyzx/Desktop/cloudforge/svn/package/innosetup/Files/FolderBrowserDialogEx.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/kennyzx/Desktop/cloudforge/svn/package/innosetup/Files/FolderBrowserDialogEx/FolderBrowserDialogEx.DLL.

```
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to use the EPPlus library in a SSIS package and I was getting this same error.
My solution was to put the file in this folder: c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/binn/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the shortcut, you probably have to set the "Start In" directory so Windows can set the Current Directory for the application.

Answer (score 0):

I used an alternative version of the EPP Plus package (a fork that purportedly fixed performance issues), and that worked where the official package failed. The alternative (unofficial) package is EPPlus.Performance.